# jQuery .on is not recognizing new link elements in a warning callout

Tags: jquery

I have the following code to display an error message if someone already has a registered email address:

```
$output['error'] = __('Email is taken. Is that you? Try to <a href="#" data-template="login">login</a> to this site or 
<a href="#" id="extend_membership_email">extend your membership to this site</a>
<input type="hidden" id="extend_membership_email_value" value="'.$input_value.'">','userpro');
```

I then have the following JS to check this:

```
$( "#extend_membership_email" ).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("it is in here");
    var email_member = $('#extend_membership_email_value').val();
    alert(email_member);
});
```

Comment: And your question is....? Also, I suspect the answer is *"use event delegation"*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) ~ see **Option 3** in the accepted answer

Comment: @Phil I thought I was using event delegation but it's not doing it.

Comment: It doesn't count if the outer element (in your case `#extend_membership_email`) is also dynamically added. You need to go up to an element that already exists like `document`. As an example, `$(document).on('click', '#extend_membership_email', function...`

Comment: @Phil That was very help and also the answer. Thanks for pointing it out. I didn't realize it wouldn't recognize new elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#extend_membership_email a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("it is in here");
    var email_member = $('#extend_membership_email_value').val();
    alert(email_member);
});
```

You need to hook the click event at document and in the second parameter you should set the target's selector (I think you want to listen to the event from an "a" inside "#extend_membership_email".

Comment: FYI, OP doesn't have any `<a>` elements under `#extend_membership_email`, it **is** the `<a>` element

Comment: So the selector should be just `#extend_membership_email` not  `#extend_membership_email a`

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding new elements, it is not working because it is when `$(document).ready()`. It gets the HTML elements / DOM  from when the page loads.

Try adding it to the HTML file (or whatever you're using) and the hiding it with

> - CSS: `display: none` / `height: 0; overflow: hidden`
> - JS: `$(object).hide()`

and when you want it to

> - Show: `$(object).show()`
> - FadeIn: `$(object).fadeIn('slow')`